# How do I change the web package version in a flutter web application?

Tags: flutter, web

I have a web app in flutter that works correctly in its current version. After changing the code for an update, I tried to run "flutter create web" but got this error:

```
...flutter create web
Recreating project web...
Resolving dependencies in web... 
Note: web is pinned to version 0.3.0 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.
Because web depends on flutter_test from sdk which depends on web 0.3.0, web 0.3.0 is required.
So, because web is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.
```

I haven't touched this project for a long time, so a lot of upgrades have been run on my environment. One of them has broken the app, I think.

Flutter doctor is as follows:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.17.0-9.0.pre.13, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.22621.2428], locale pt-BR)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources
```

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

I would like to know where this "web is 1.0.0+1" is configured and if it can be changed.

For some context: the apk version compiles and runs correctly; and I created the flutter demo project in the current environment, and it runs on the browser (with flutter run) but the create web command gives the same error.

I've been told that probably I'll have to downgrade the flutter sdk, but I really don't know if it will work.

Thanks for any help.